# How to make Python version executables global across multiple pyenv-virtualenv virtual environments

Tags: pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

A `pyenv` Python version (e.g. `3.10.4`) has the "normal" expected Python executables associated with it (e.g., `pip`, `2to3`, `pydoc`)

```
$ ls "${PYENV_ROOT}/versions/3.10.4/bin"
2to3       idle   idle3.10  pip3     pydoc   pydoc3.10  python-config  python3-config  python3.10-config
2to3-3.10  idle3  pip       pip3.10  pydoc3  python python3        python3.10      python3.10-gdb.py
```

and a `pyenv-virtualenv` virtual environment has only the executables that one would a get inside the virtual environment directory structure

```
$ pyenv virtualenv 3.10.4 venv
$ ls "${PYENV_ROOT}/versions/venv"
bin  include  lib  lib64  pyvenv.cfg
$ ls "${PYENV_ROOT}/versions/venv/bin/"
Activate.ps1  activate  activate.csh  activate.fish  pip  pip3  pip3.10  pydoc  python  python3  python3.10
```

by default after creation, the `venv` virtual environment doesn't know about executables of the Python version that it is associated to, like `2to3`

```
$ pyenv activate venv
(venv) $ 2to3 --help
pyenv: 2to3: command not found

The `2to3' command exists in these Python versions:
  3.10.4

Note: See 'pyenv help global' for tips on allowing both
      python2 and python3 to be found.
```

so to allow for a virtual environment like `venv` to have access to these executables you add both it and the Python that created it to `pyenv global` so that `pyenv` will ["fall back"](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/16#issuecomment-37640961) to the Python version when the executable isn't found

```
(venv) $ pyenv deactivate
$ pyenv global venv 3.10.4
(venv) $ pyenv global 
venv
3.10.4
(venv) $ 2to3 --help | head -n 3
Usage: 2to3 [options] file|dir ...

Options:
```

This pattern works for one virtual environment, but how do you maintain access to executables like `2to3` (or `pipx` as seen below`) when you have multiple virtual environments in play?

```
(venv) $ pyenv virtualenv 3.10.4 example && pyenv activate example
(example) $ 2to3  
pyenv: 2to3: command not found

The `2to3' command exists in these Python versions:
  3.10.4

Note: See 'pyenv help global' for tips on allowing both
      python2 and python3 to be found.
```

### Reproducible example

Using the following Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:bullseye

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
USER root

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        make \
        build-essential \
        libssl-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libbz2-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        wget \
        curl \
        llvm \
        libncurses5-dev \
        xz-utils \
        tk-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxmlsec1-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        liblzma-dev \
        g++ && \
    apt-get install -y \
        git && \
    apt-get -y clean && \
    apt-get -y autoremove && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv
ENV PYENV_RELEASE_VERSION=2.3.0
RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git \
        --branch "v${PYENV_RELEASE_VERSION}" \
        --single-branch \
        ~/.pyenv && \
    pushd ~/.pyenv && \
    src/configure && \
    make -C src && \
    echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="${HOME}/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo 'export PATH="${PYENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"' >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc && \
    . ~/.bashrc && \
    git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv.git $(pyenv root)/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv && \
    echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc

# Install CPython
ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.10.4
RUN . ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "Install Python ${PYTHON_VERSION}" && \
    PYTHON_MAKE_OPTS="-j8" pyenv install "${PYTHON_VERSION}"

# Make 'base' virtual envirionment, add it and its Python version to global for
# executables like 2to3 or pipx to be findable
# c.f. https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/16#issuecomment-37640961
# and then install pipx into the 'base' virtual environment and use pipx to install
# pepotron
RUN . ~/.bashrc && \
    pyenv virtualenv "${PYTHON_VERSION}" base && \
    echo "" && echo "Python ${PYTHON_VERSION} has additional executables..." && \
    ls -lh "${PYENV_ROOT}/versions/${PYTHON_VERSION}/bin" && \
    echo "" && echo "...compared to 'base' virtualenv made with Python ${PYTHON_VERSION}" && \
    ls -lh "${PYENV_ROOT}/versions/base/bin" && \
    echo "" && echo "...because 'base' is actually a symlink" && \
    ls -lh "${PYENV_ROOT}/versions/" && \
    pyenv global base "${PYTHON_VERSION}" && \
    python -m pip --quiet install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel && \
    python -m pip --quiet install pipx && \
    python -m pipx ensurepath && \
    eval "$(register-python-argcomplete pipx)" && \
    pipx install pepotron

WORKDIR /home/data
```

built with

```
docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag pyenv/multiple-virtualenvs:debug
```

it can be run with the following to demonstrate the problem

```
$ docker run --rm -ti pyenv/multiple-virtualenvs:debug
(base) root@26dfa530cd82:/home/data# pyenv global 
base
3.10.4
(base) root@26dfa530cd82:/home/data# 2to3 --help | head -n 3
Usage: 2to3 [options] file|dir ...

Options:
(base) root@26dfa530cd82:/home/data# pipx list
venvs are in /root/.local/pipx/venvs
apps are exposed on your $PATH at /root/.local/bin
   package pepotron 0.6.0, installed using Python 3.10.4
    - bpo
    - pep
(base) root@26dfa530cd82:/home/data# pep 3.11
https://peps.python.org/pep-0664/
(base) root@26dfa530cd82:/home/data# pyenv virtualenv 3.10.4 example                          
(base) root@26dfa530cd82:/home/data# pyenv activate example
pyenv-virtualenv: prompt changing will be removed from future release. configure `export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1' to simulate the behavior.
(example) root@26dfa530cd82:/home/data# 2to3
pyenv: 2to3: command not found

The `2to3' command exists in these Python versions:
  3.10.4

Note: See 'pyenv help global' for tips on allowing both
      python2 and python3 to be found.
(example) root@26dfa530cd82:/home/data# pipx
pyenv: pipx: command not found

The `pipx' command exists in these Python versions:
  3.10.4/envs/base
  base

Note: See 'pyenv help global' for tips on allowing both
      python2 and python3 to be found.
```

So how can one have something like `pipx`, that is designed to be installed globally, work globally if it is installed in a `pyenv-virtualenv` virtual environment so that you don't have to have anything installed with `pip` in the system Python?

It would seem that instead of ever using `pyenv activate` to activate a virtual environment you would need to deactivate any virtual environments and then only use `pyenv global <virtual environment name> <virtual environment Python version>` to effectively switch environments. I assume that can't be the only way to use Python version executables inside of a virtual environment, as that seems like that would remove the point of having a separate `pyenv activate` CLI API for `pyenv-virtualenv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly execute the `pipx` binary in the pyenv prefix, it should work correctly.

Pyenv's shims mechanism isn't really designed for global binaries like this. I naively expected that the global environment would act as fallback when a local environment doesn't have an installed binary, but I think pyenv only looks at the system Python before falling back to $PATH.

So, if you don't install `pipx` into `system` (which, if you're not installing a system `pip`, I doubt you're doing), then the naive fallback doesn't work.
An alternative is to run `pyenv` with a temporary environment, i.e.
`PYENV_VERSION=my-pipx-env pyenv exec pipx`.

I'd want to make this an executable, so I'd suggest adding something like this into a special PATH directory that takes precedence from the pyenv paths:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

export PYENV_VERSION="pipx"
exec "${PYENV_ROOT}/libexec/pyenv" exec pipx "$@"
```

Although, I'd be tempted to forgo the whole activation logic and just directly `exec` the `pipx` binary from the environment `/bin` to avoid running into any shell configuration errors.